# Remove Win8 Lock screen and show password on mouse move?

Tags: windows-8, login, desktop-customization, login-screen, lock-screen

When locking windows and returning back to my desk, I see a wallpaper and some info, which is really cool and I love it:

[image]

The problem is, in Windows 7 I could type in the password right when the screen is dark, and press enter.
In Window 8 I have to press a button, and wait for the view to switch to the unlock screen, and then type in my password and unlock it.
Is there any way to avoid this?

[image]

Comment: You can just hit enter and start typing. The characters will still get entered even if the lock screen hasn't disappeared yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not without disabling that new LockScreen you seem to love :) If you are willing to do that there is a group policy setting for it. In fact i have written an entire article on how to do it over at [How-To Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/110283/how-to-disable-the-lock-screen-in-windows-8/).

To summarize:

- Open a run box then type gpedit.msc to open the group policy management console
- Navigate to 
  `Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Control Panel -> Personalization`
- Enable the `Do not display the lock screen` setting on the right hand side.

Comment: Way to go you rock man!

Comment: But it wasn't the lock screen I loved, it was the picture, now it's gone... Anyway hitting a button before is more frustrating after all. I hate to press unnecessary buttons. And no, I do type blindly and extremely fast }:)

Comment: I wish the password text box would be embedded into the lockscreen image...

Comment: @Shimmy yeah sometimes you just have to make sacrifices :) glad you got it sorted though

Comment: This option doesn't work anymore. Since build 14295 release 160318-1628.